# Showing that $ \sum \limits_{m=1}^{n} b_m x_{m-n}~\to~ ab$ as $n~\to~\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If $x_n ~\to ~a$ as $n~ \to~ \infty$

Does:
$ \sum \limits_{m=1}^{n} b_m x_{n-m}~\to~ ab$ as $n~\to~\infty$?

$b_m ~\geq~0$ and $ b~\equiv~ \sum \limits_{m=1}^{\infty} b_m < \infty$

**My attempt:**

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n~=~a$

I would like to have something like this I think

$$\inf x_n \sum_{m=1}^n b_m~\leq~\sum b_m x_{n-m}~\leq ~\sup x_n \sum_{m=1}^n b_m$$

Then taking the limits will squeeze it in to $ab$, I am having trouble getting this form, is there any easier way to do this?

i.e. $$\sum_{m=1}^n b_m\inf x_{n-m} ~\leq~\sum b_m x_{n-m}~\leq ~\sum_{m=1}^n b_m\sup x_{n-m} $$

Then $\sup x_{n-m} \leq \sup x_n$ and $\inf x_{n-m} \geq \inf x_n$

Is $b_m \geq 0$ necessary?

Comment: Often these kind of results involve dividing the terms which approach a limit into two parts: A first part which is not close to the limit but can eventually be disregarded, and the rest which is close to the limit so that, in your case, you can argue that $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ for $n > N(\epsilon)$.

Comment: I think you should change $x_{m-n}$ to $x_{n-m}$ in a couple of places.

Comment: Change $b_m x_{n-m}$ to $x_m b_{n-m}$ ?

Comment: I suspect that you did not copy your problem correctly.

Comment: @shilov Let me put it this way: $\sum_{m=1}^n b_mx_{n-m}\neq \sum_{m=1}^n b_mx_{m-n}$. Look *carefully*....

Comment: As a matter of fact, for consistency, I reckon it should even be $b_m x_{n-m+1}$ (so that the range of indices for $x_i$ is $\{1,\dots, n\}$ instead of $\{0,\dots, n-1\}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{m=1}^n b_m x_{n-m+1} - ab \right|
&= \left| \sum_{m=1}^n b_m x_{n-m+1} - a\sum_{m=1}^n b_m + a\sum_{m=1}^n b_m - ab \right|\\
&\leq \left|\sum_{m=1}^n b_m x_{n-m+1} - a\sum_{m=1}^n b_m \right| + \left|a\sum_{m=1}^n b_m - ab \right| \\
&\leq \left|\sum_{m=1}^n b_m \left( x_{n-m+1} - a\right) \right| + \left|a\left( \sum_{m=1}^n b_m - b\right)\right| \\
&\leq \left|\sum_{m=1}^n b_{n-m+1} \left( x_m - a\right) \right| + |a|\left| \sum_{m=1}^n b_m - b\right|          \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align*}
$$
The second term goes to $0$ by convergence of the series $\sum b_m$, so it only remains to deal with the first one. Define the sequence $(a_n)_n$ by $a_n = x_n -a$ (so that it converges to $0$), and fix any $\varepsilon > 0$: there exists $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N_\varepsilon$, $|a_n|\leq \varepsilon$.

Now, for any $n \geq N_\varepsilon$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta_n\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\left|\sum_{m=1}^n b_{n-m+1} \left( x_m - a\right) \right| 
&= \left|\sum_{m=1}^n b_{n-m+1} a_m \right|
= \left|\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1} a_m + \sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} b_{n-m+1} a_m \right| \\
&\leq \left|\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1} a_m\right| + \left|\sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} b_{n-m+1} a_m \right| \\
&\leq \sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} \left|b_{n-m+1} a_m\right| + \sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} \left|b_{n-m+1} a_m \right| \\
&\leq \underbrace{\max_{1\leq k \leq N_\varepsilon-1}|a_k|}_{\alpha_{\varepsilon}}\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1}  + \varepsilon\sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} b_{n-m+1} \qquad ((b_k)\text{ non-negative})\\
&= \alpha_{\varepsilon}\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1}  + \varepsilon\sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} b_{n-m+1}
\end{align*}
$$
Finally, $0\leq \sum_{N_\varepsilon}^{n} b_{n-m+1} \leq \sum_{1}^{\infty} b_{n} = b$ (it actually converges when $n\to+\infty$ (monotone convergence) to some $b_\varepsilon\leq b$); while $\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1}$ is the sum of constantly many ($N_\varepsilon-1$ to be precise) terms, each of them going to $0$ as $n\to+\infty$ (since $\sum b_k$ converges, $b_k\to 0$), and therefore $\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Therefore, there exists $N^\prime_\varepsilon \geq N_\varepsilon$ such that for all $n\geq N^\prime_\varepsilon$, $\alpha_\varepsilon\sum_{m=1}^{N_\varepsilon-1} b_{n-m+1}\leq b\varepsilon$:
$$
\forall n\geq N^\prime_\varepsilon,\ \Delta_n\leq 2b\varepsilon
$$
i.e. $\Delta_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Thus the first term of ($\dagger$) goes to $0$ as well, proving that
$$
\left| \sum_{m=1}^n b_m x_{n-m+1} - ab \right|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0
$$

Comment: (Provided I didn't screw up in the middle of the proof.)

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your sum as $$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} b_{n-m} x_m$$ Define $$a_{n,m}=\frac{b_{n-m}}{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}, m=0,\cdots,n$$ and $a_{n,m}=0$ for $m>n$. Then $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{n,m}=1$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,m}=0/b=0$. By [Silverman-Toeplitz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{n,m}x_m=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} b_{n-m} x_m}{\sum_{k=1}^n b_k}=a$$ Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n b_k=b$, we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} b_{n-m} x_m=ab$$